# How to draw table in d3.js with the given different arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

How to draw a table in d3.js if we have 3 different arrays for row, columns and data respectively? Suppose I have an array as, colsname={1,2,3}, rowname={a,b,c} and data={10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18}. How would I draw a table with this information ? (Provided the values for row is in rowname, column in colsname).

Answer (score -1):

Try looking through some of the D3.js examples on bl.ocks for inspiration. For example: http://bl.ocks.org/AMDS/4a61497182b8fcb05906